# How do I correctly handle redirects for bad url's to custom 404 page in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

Users can access others users profiles like this:

site.com/username

My find method in my users controller will find the user by their username.. now if the user doesn't exist I want them re-directed to a custom 404 error page I'll make.

I also want them re-directed for any other non-existant url's they type in.

I've found some solutions on google but wondering if someone can give me an up to date example of doing this in rails 3.2 as theses tutorials I've found are pre rails 3.1.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In production an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception will automatically render your `public/404.html` file.

Comment: What if I wish to see this in development mode? how would I handle that?

Comment: Are you asking how to simply see your 404 page in general? Http://localhost:3000/404.html

Comment: Yep, I'd like to be as close to the experience my users will have as possible but all in development mode. So seeing 404 pages when a bad URL is typed in is a must.

Answer (score 7):

I tried this solution with Rails 3.2 and it just works.

https://makandracards.com/makandra/12807-custom-error-pages-in-rails-3-2

1. In your `config/application.rb`

   ```
   config.exceptions_app = self.routes
   ```
2. In your `config/routes.rb`

   ```
   get '/404', to: 'errors#not_found'
   get '/500', to: 'errors#server_error'
   ```
3. Create `app/controllers/errors_controller.rb`

   ```
   class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
     def not_found
       render status: 404
     end

     def server_error
       render status: 500
     end
   end
   ```
4. Create `app/views/errors/not_found.html.haml` and `app/views/errors/server_error.html.haml` (replace `haml` by `erb` if you do not use haml)
5. Restart your server

Answer (score 0):

you can always render template 404 along with status code when `record is not found` or `invalid URL` entered

```
render :template => 'public/404.html', :status => 404
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the blog for "custom dynamic error pages in ruby on rails" will help you

[custom dynamic error pages in ruby on rails](http://www.perfectline.ee/blog/custom-dynamic-error-pages-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score -1):

isnt it just in /public/404.html ?

UPDATE

Actually im pretty sure it is, that the same exact 404 page that comes up while running my page on nginx in production mode.